# How to render block using jinja2 API

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to code my own static page generator with jinja2. I want to render something programmatically in a specific block. I tried this:

```
import jinja2

a = "adam"
b = "bob"

template = jinja2.Template(u"{{ A }} {% block b %}{% endblock %}")

html = template.render({'A': a, 'B': b})

print(html)
```

But the following output is returned: `adam`. How can I render some text and/or variables (for instance variable `b`) in the b block.

Comment: Thank you for the concise code sample. But can you be more specific: Are you expecting the output to be `adam`, or are you getting `adam` but expecting somehting else?

Comment: I realize that my problem is "how to render something in a specific block", i'm updating the question.

Comment: I'm sort of confused as to why you'd want to do this. Why not just use `{{ B }}`? Blocks like you've provided are typically used when you need to fill in the block with the value of a child template, which you're not using.

Comment: To be honest I was trying to mimick the behabior of pelican but in fact the best solution is not to search to update block myself but insert a {{ ... }} in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template blocks are only used for template inheritance. So for example, when you have a second template that extends the previous, you can replace the created block with something else by filling the block in the inherited template.

However, when calling `render()`, the template context you passing only defines the *variables* that are used inside of the template. Blocks cannot be filled by templates and as such your `B` won’t just appear. The content of the block is still empty and as such nothing will appear.

If you want to display variable content, you will have to specify a variable like you did for `A`. You can however combine both and provide a block `B` with the default content being the variable output. Then in inherited templates, you could still overwrite the block with something else.

```
template = jinja2.Template(u"{{ A }} {% block B %}{{ B }}{% endblock %}")
template.render({'A': a, 'B': b})
```

Btw.: blocks and variables can actually share the same name without conflicting each other.

Comment: Correct: except the `b` should be a `B` in the block.

Comment: @MarkHildreth Right; or both `B` as I actually wanted to highlight the possibility to name them identically. Fixed, thanks :)